# I'm using Ruby on Rails and I want to delete a db entry. Can I "cut" the entry and have all of the bigger IDs decrease by one?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

For example, if I have a database with 3 entries and I want to delete entry #2. From now on when I call database.find(2) it returns nothing, but I'd like for entry #3 to change down to #2 once I have deleted one below it.  I'm super new to this, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is: no. The reasons are:

- It was an early design decision of Rails to have technical keys only and to use integer values from 0 on automatically.
- It is not at all easy to switch IDs and keep all references working.
- The set of IDs is nearly endless, so what could be the value to have integer IDs without "holes" in the sequence.

So you just have to get used to it :-)

Comment: Ok, interesting. Thanks. I was trying to display a random entry from the database by just calling database.find(1+rand(database.count)), but obviously things get messed up once I have empty spaces in the database. I guess this will require a bit more thought...

Comment: Agreed, don't mess with ids. If you need to find a random record, try selecting the first one using `:order => 'RAND()'` instead.